# Issues with centring section, header is fixed and width is 100%

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm trying to make the section to be centred to the screen. The header is fixed and header-container is fixed as well. Header-container contains the logo, nav and social links.

Saying the header and header-container are using `top:0;`, I can't seem to get my head around to getting it to work. I know by using `margin: 0 auto;` would centre it, but not in this case.

Edit: Whenever I seem to centre it, when I zoom out it shoots to the left side, The header seems to stay centred, which is the result that I'm looking for.

[image: Screenshot]

*HTML:*

```
<header>
    <div id="header-container">
        <nav></nav>
        <div id="social"></div>
    </div>
</header>
<section></section>
```

*CSS:*

```
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1048px;
    min-height: 800px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 86px;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    background-image: url("../images/header-banner.png");
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5d5d5d;
}
div#header-container {
    width: 1048px;
    height: 86px;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
section {
    width: 1048px;
    min-height: 500px;
    background:#fff;
    margin:86px auto 0;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot without seeing your **html markup**

Comment: Just added the html code.

Comment: Used your code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tp5QT/) just changing some `background-color` properties and it looks fine to me. I would look for other external styles that could be affecting the output.
I also added a `left: 0` to your header since there was some space before it on the "left".

Comment: same for me here : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/58Pas/1/ do you have some properties on the body tag in your real project?

Comment: @web-tiki The body is just a grey background, I don't really want 100% on the section area. Thanks for the help, I was fairly close. I'll try and implement solution and star it.

Comment: @Callistno I'll star this once I have it. Thanks!

Comment: @web-tiki I just added the body css.

Comment: @Callistno see comment above. I think the body css is affecting it, because I added the left:0 and nothing changed.

Comment: well... Everything seems right with this CSS : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/58Pas/2/

Comment: It must be the #wrapper then, just added the code.

Comment: I can't seem to make it display properly, but the wrapper css is in there, the HTML isn't working when I place it in, but the #wrapper contains the header and section.

Comment: @web-tiki See comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your width is 100% of it's container, `margin: 0 auto;` will not work in most browsers. Change it to 98% and it will correctly auto center. This will also happen if the width is set by pixels or any other measurement type.